# C - dynamical allocation/rellocation inside the function

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault, malloc, realloc

I have written this function in C (function should receive a `char*`, allocate space necessary, and insert character given a pointer to the index of character behind the pointer)

```
void add_to_str(char *character, char ** string, int* index)
{
    //we dont expect  *string to be NULL !! no condition done
    if (*index == 0)    //if str is empty we will alloc AVGLEN(32) characters space
       *string=malloc(AVGLEN*sizeof(char));

    if (*string == NULL)   //malloc fails?
    {
        fprintf(stderr,errors[MALLOC]);
        exit(99);
    }
    //string length exceeds 32 characters we will allocate more space
    if ( *index > (AVGLEN-1) || character== NULL )// or string buffering ended, we will free redundant space
    {
        *string=realloc(*string,sizeof(char)*((*index)+2));//+1 == '\0' & +1 bcs we index from 0
        if (*string==NULL)   //realloc fails?
        {
            fprintf(stderr,errors[REALLOC]);
            exit(99);
        }
    }
    *string[(*index)++]=*character;
}
```

When `*index > 0`, it gives me a segmentation fault on the line

```
*string[(*index)++]=*character;
```

A variant of this function (just `malloc` behind `char*` and then assign characters to `string[i++]`) works perfectly.

Comment: I suggest moving any `++` and such inside any non-trivial expressions to their own statements. Compiler should still produce same output after optimizations, and you may avoid some unexpected behavior and have clearer code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful with this statement:

```
*string[(*index)++]=*character;
```

Because array indexing has higher precedence than pointer dereferencing. Thus, this is the same as

```
*(string[(*index)++]) = *character;
```

Which is not what you want. You want this:

```
(*string)[(*index)++] = *character;
```

The faulty code works for `*index == 0` because in that case the statement is equivalent to `**string`, which is still valid, but when `index > 0`, `string` is going to be dereferenced in an invalid position: `string+index`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that doing something like this:

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, ...);
```

is a really bad pattern. When `realloc()` fails your old allocated area is no longer accessible to the program and becomes leaked. The correct pattern would be:

```
char* str_new = realloc(string, ...);

if (str_new != NULL)
    string = str_new;
else
    /* handle allocation error */
```

Comment: yeah i see now, btw in this program certainly its true that i dont need the rest of a string when reallocation fails, but at least i can free() it carefully, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For a start the function `fprintf` requires a format string.

I.e.

```
 fprintf(stderr,errors[MALLOC]);
```

is probably invalid.

Also what is the purpose of this function. Seems to have no narrative,

Comment: btw it works errors* is a form of associative string array (smt like this)const char* const errors[] =
{
 [MALLOC] = "ERROR: Malloc()'s dynamic memory alocation failed\n"
}